# MKVMERGE & cmd Batch Muxing Video and Subtitles

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe, matroska

My scenario:

I have multiple mkv files with separate but corresponding srt files in a folder that I want to mux together.

I'm only interested in the files in the current directory and I'm running the script from a cmd window on Win10 x64.

I want to write the resulting muxed files into a new sub-directory under the original directory.

Example:

- video1.mkv
- subtitle1.srt
- video2.mkv
- subtitle2.srt
- video3.mkv
- subtitle3.srt

I found a thread with a script that does pretty much what I want to do here: https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/365907-MKVMERGE-Batch-Muxing-multiple-audio-and-su...ks#post2407646

I've modified that script to this:

```
for %%a in (.) do call :set_file_names
:set_file_names
    set "output_name="
    set "input_name="
    set "subtitle_name="
    for %%m in (*.mkv) do set "output_name=%%~dpmtemp\%%~nxm" & set "input_name=%%~nxm"
    for %%m in (*.srt) do set "subtitle_name=%%~nxm" & call :mux
:mux
    echo ***** Starting MKVmerge *****
    "C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" -o "%output_name%" --language 0:eng --default-track-flag 0:yes --audio-tracks 1 --language 1:eng --default-track-flag 1:yes "%input_name%" --language 0:eng --track-name 0:English "%subtitle_name%"
```

My problem is the line setting the mkv files name always results in the last (third in my example) file name.

It correctly iterates through the subtitle file names producing:

- video3.mkv + subtitle1.srt
- video3.mkv + subtitle2.srt
- video3.mkv + subtitle3.srt

I'm sure there's an easy fix, but being a batch file newbie, it's not obvious to me!

Can anyone help?

Update #1:
Based on comments by @stephan, my script now looks like this and I seem to be closer to the answer, but it still doesn't work:

```
for %%M in (*.mkv) do (
    for %%S in (%%~n_*.srt) do (
        "C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" -o "%%~dpMtemp\%%~nxM" "%%~nxM" "%%~nxS"
    )
)
```

When executed, this produces 3 mkvmerge results with the correct mkv file and without any srt file. The script doesn't seem to be getting the srt file name correctly?
[Screen shot of script results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jxwM.jpg)
Any suggestions?

Comment: "corresponding" - how? Do they share (part of) the same filename? Can you give some examples?

Comment: If the the video filename is video1.mkv, the subtitle filename would be video1_OS_English.srt or video1_OS_English_CC.srt. The names are created automatically by the program I use to find and add subtitles. I know I can rename the files so the root filename matches, but I was trying to avoid that if I can.  Also, my next step is to write a similar script that will find and merge mkv files with idx and sub subtitle files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So someone on another forum came up with an answer that works for me:

```
@echo off
set /a "outernum=0"
for %%m in (*.mkv) do set "output_name=%%~dpmtemp\%%~nxm" & set "input_name=%%~nxm" & call :inner
exit /b

:inner
    set /a "innernum=0"
    for %%m in (*.srt) do set "subtitle_name=%%~nxm" & call :mux
    set /a "outernum+=1"
    exit /b

:mux
    if %outernum% equ %innernum% (
        echo ***** Starting MKVmerge *****
        "C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" -o "%output_name%" "%input_name%" "%subtitle_name%"
    )
    set /a "innernum+=1"
```

[The answer can be seen in context here](https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/406929-Need-help-With-MKVMERGE-Batch-Muxing-Video-and-Subtitles#post2667278)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop over the `.mkv`**and** over the `.srt` files. Just loop over the `.mkv` files and let the script search for the matching `srt` (easy, as the `.srt` starts with the same title).

Untested, so you might need to tweak a bit (I don't know anything about the `mkvmerge` syntax).

```
@echo off
for %%M in (*.mkv') do (
  for %%S in (%%~nM_*.srt) do (
    "C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" -o "%%~dpMtemp\%%~nxM" --language 0:eng --default-track-flag 0:yes --audio-tracks 1 --language 1:eng --default-track-flag 1:yes "%%M" --language 0:eng --track-name 0:English "%%S"
  )
)
```

Attention: if you have different `.srt` files (different languages), this will try to create several output files with the same name (don't know how mkvmerge will behave in this case)

Comment: thanks for your help, but it still doesn't work. I've edited my original post to reflect my results.

Comment: simple typo (missed a `M`) - corrected,.

Answer (score 0):

```batch
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cd /d "%~dp0" && 2>nul mkdir "%~dp0temp"

set "_mkv="C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe""
set "_arg_0=--verbose --priority higher --default-track-flag 0:yes --track-name 0:_SRT_"
set "_arg_1= --language 0:eng File_SRT --flush-on-close --disable-track-statistics-tags"

for %%i in =;(*.mkv);= do for %%I in =;("%%~ni*.srt");= do echo\"%%~nxI" | 2>nul findstr /i _CC\.srt >nul && =;(
     !_mkv! -o ".\temp\%%~nxi" ".\%%~nxi" !_arg_0:_SRT_=ClosedCaption! !_arg_1:File_SRT=".\%%~nxI"! | findstr ':
    );= || !_mkv! -o ".\temp\%%~nxi" ".\%%~nxi" !_arg_0:_SRT_=English! !_arg_1:File_SRT=".\%%~nxI"! | findstr ':
       
endlocal && goto :eof
```

Files:

```batch
video1.mkv
video1_OS_English_CC.srt
video2.mkv
video2_OS_English.srt
```

Command lines:

```batch
"C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" -o ".\temp\video1.mkv" ".\video1.mkv" --verbose --priority higher --default-track-flag 0:yes --track-name 0:ClosedCaption --language 0:eng ".\video1_OS_English_CC.srt" --flush-on-close --disable-track-statistics-tags
"C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" -o ".\temp\video2.mkv" ".\video2.mkv" --verbose --priority higher --default-track-flag 0:yes --track-name 0:English --language 0:eng ".\video2_OS_English.srt" --flush-on-close --disable-track-statistics-tags
```

Outputs:

```batch
'.\video1.mkv': Using the demultiplexer for the format 'Matroska'.
'.\video1_OS_English_CC.srt': Using the demultiplexer for the format 'SRT subtitles'.
'.\video2.mkv': Using the demultiplexer for the format 'Matroska'.
'.\video2_OS_English.srt': Using the demultiplexer for the format 'SRT subtitles'.
```

[The answer can be seen in context here](https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/406929-Need-help-With-MKVMERGE-Batch-Muxing-Video-and-Subtitles#post2667372)

Comment: Thanks for your help @lo-ol!